# How to kill a Activity and the AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask

i am working on a little game. When I press the backbutton the `activity` will show a window cancel game **yes/no**.

If I press Yes i get via `finish()` back to my `MainActivity`.

My Problem is, that I can't start the game again, because my Asynctask wasn't finished. I first have to kill the app in the "recently used apps".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement two things to stop the AsyncTask execution:
 
1. call Cancel() method of AsyncTask from where you want to stop the execution. This could be in `onStop()` of your Activity , like below:
`asyncTask.cancel(true);`
 
 2. Now you have to check whether the AsyncTask is cancelled or not by using isCancelled method inside the doInBackground method.

```
protected Object doInBackground(Object... x)  { 

   while (/* condition */)
   {
      ...
      if (isCancelled())  
         break;
   } 
   return null; 
}
```

Why? Because of below description from Android docs for AsyncTask:

> Cancelling a task
>  A task can be cancelled at any time by invoking
>   cancel(boolean). Invoking this method will cause subsequent calls to
>   isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method,
>   onCancelled(Object), instead of onPostExecute(Object) will be invoked
>   after doInBackground(Object[]) returns. To ensure that a task is
>   cancelled as quickly as possible, you should always check the return
>   value of isCancelled() periodically from doInBackground(Object[]), if
>   possible (inside a loop for instance.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to cancel the `AsyncTask` in the Activity's `onStop`.

Answer (score 1):

you can refer to this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#cancel%28boolean%29) for cancelling your async task

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using surface to code the actual game part instead of activity, that might help you get rip of this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Used it for a Camera Application already, but didn't think of using it for the Game.

Answer (score 0):

In the code to handle click

- 1> Call finish(), and use AsyncTask.cancel() method on onStop() or onDestroy().
- or 2> use AsyncTask.cancel(), and in AsyncTask.onCancelled() method, call finish() to end activity.

1> is common used.